# How to push onto a hash key of array?

Tags: raku

I am trying to push onto a hash of an array in Perl6.

The perl5 equivalent is:

```
my %c;
@{ $c{'USA'} } = qw(Seattle Madison Bozeman Portland);
push @{ $c{'USA'} }, 'Philadelphia';
```

but this in Perl6:

```
my %c;
%c<USA> = 'Seattle', 'Madison', 'Bozeman', 'Portland';
%c{'USA'}.append: 'Philadelphia';
```

gives this error

> Cannot call 'append' on an immutable 'List'

I get a similar error for Perl6's `push`, which would seem to be okay given the example from https://docs.perl6.org/routine/push which shows `%h<a>.push(1);` Trying `%c<USA>.push('Philadelphia')` also fails

what am I doing wrong here? I don't see this error on search engine results

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
my %c;
%c<USA> = ['Seattle', 'Madison', 'Bozeman', 'Portland'];
%c{'USA'}.append: 'Philadelphia';
```

The brackets make an [`Array`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/list#Arrays) instead of a [`List`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/list#Literal_lists)

Links are to the [Lists, sequences, and arrays](https://docs.perl6.org/language/list) docs which explain the difference, the primary being that List is immutable, while Array is not.

Comment: Incidently, you can use <Seattle Madison Bozeman Portland> to quote words like Perl 5 qw().

Comment: So you could write `%c<USA> = <Seattle Madison Bozeman Portland>;`. So no commas or quotes. Also you could write `%c<USA>.append: 'Philadelphia';` (or `%c<USA>.append: <Philadelphia>;`).

Comment: @raiph, that still requires square brackets so that an array is created. Fortunately, square and angle brackets compose perfectly: `my %c; %c<USA> = [<Seattle Madison Bozeman Portland>]; %c<USA>.append: 'Philadelphia';`. Btw, for single elements you can .push instead, and you can even push a pair into the hash to create or extend arrays in it: `%c.push((USA => "Philadelphia"))`. Note the double parens to make it a positional Pair parameter instead of a named argument.

Comment: Duh. Thanks @timotimo. (I do actually know this stuff but I deliberately got it wrong so that you'd write an awesome follow up comment. >.>) One could still write `%c<USA>.append: <Philadelphia>;` though, because the target data structure (stored in `%c<USA>`) is already established as a mutable array by then and the list of arguments (`<Philadelphia>`) are just appended to that already existing array. (He said, hoping he was right... >.>)